# Trying to change active tab color, don't know what I am doing wrong in my code

Tags: javascript, html

The active selected tab should be changing as well as the text inside of the box but it isn't and I can't figure out why.
I have made a fiddle to show what I have done so far:

```js
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

  // This what happens when clicked on the FIRST button
  function click1() {
    btn1.classList.add("search-tab selected"); // give the selected class
    btn2.classList.remove("search-tab selected"); // take away the selected class
  }

  // This what happens when clicked on the SECOND button
  function click2() {
    btn2.classList.add("search-tab selected"); // give the selected class
    btn1.classList.remove("search-tab selected"); // take away the selected class
  }
```

```css
/*! CSS Used from: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css */
header,nav{display:block;}
a{background-color:transparent;}
a:active,a:hover{outline:0;}
img{border:0;}
input{margin:0;font:inherit;color:inherit;}
input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
input::-moz-focus-inner{padding:0;border:0;}
input{line-height:normal;}
@media print{
*,:after,:before{color:#000!important;text-shadow:none!important;background:0 0!important;-webkit-box-shadow:none!important;box-shadow:none!important;}
a,a:visited{text-decoration:underline;}
a[href]:after{content:" (" attr(href) ")";}
img{page-break-inside:avoid;}
img{max-width:100%!important;}
h2,p{orphans:3;widows:3;}
h2{page-break-after:avoid;}
}
*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
:after,:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
input{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit;}
a{color:#337ab7;text-decoration:none;}
a:focus,a:hover{color:#23527c;text-decoration:underline;}
a:focus{outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px;}
img{vertical-align:middle;}
h2{font-family:inherit;font-weight:500;line-height:1.1;color:inherit;}
h2{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:10px;}
h2{font-size:30px;}
p{margin:0 0 10px;}
ul{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:10px;}
ul ul{margin-bottom:0;}
.row{margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px;}
.col-md-12{position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;}
@media (min-width:992px){
.col-md-12{float:left;}
.col-md-12{width:100%;}
}
.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before,.row:after,.row:before{display:table;content:" ";}
.clearfix:after,.row:after{clear:both;}

img{border:0;}
.amh-content:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both;}
#header{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;clear:both;}
#header{background-position:center;min-height:100px;}
@media (max-width: 992px){
img{max-width:100%!important;height:auto!important;}
}
.clearfix:after{content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
.amh-row{margin:0 auto;padding:0;}
.amh-block{padding:0;margin:0;}
.amh-content{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
@media (max-width: 767px){
div.amh-row > div.amh-block > div.amh-content{margin-left:auto!important;margin-right:auto!important;}
}

a{text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
a{font-weight:normal;}
#header>.amh-row{max-width:988px;}
#header>.amh-row>.amh-block>.amh-content{max-width:988px;}
a{color:#00b0b0;}
a:hover{color:#00d6d6;}
h2{color:#377275;padding-bottom:2px;padding-top:2px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;line-height:1.3;}
h2{padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;}
h2{font-weight:bold;font-size:2.667em;}
#siteMenu > h2 > img{float:right;}
#search-box > div.search-tab-content{padding:12px!important;}
div,form{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;vertical-align:baseline;}
input[type=submit]{background-color:#4f2683;color:#fff;border:0;padding:6px;cursor:pointer;}
@media handheld, screen and (min-width: 620px){
#mobile-search{display:none;}
}
input[type="submit"]:hover{background:#807f83;color:#eee;}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 619px){
#mobile-search{margin-left:5px;position:relative;display:block;}
#mobile-search div{margin-bottom:10px;}
#mobile-search-field{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:70%;border-radius:0px!important;margin:0;font-size:24px;padding:8px 0 8px 8px;border:solid 5px #c9c9c9;line-height:24px;box-sizing:border-box;}
input[type="text"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:none;border-radius:0;}
#mobile-search-submit{width:28%;height:100%;margin:0;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;line-height:42px;text-indent:-9999px;background-image:url("");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;}
}
div,a,img,nav{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;vertical-align:baseline;}
nav{display:block;}
h2{padding:0;margin:0 0 10px 0;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;color:#323232;}
a,a:visited{color:#4f2683;text-decoration:none;}
a:active,a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
ul{margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:-5px;}
ul ul{margin:0;}
a{font-weight:700;}
@media handheld, screen and (min-width: 620px){
#menuContainer ul{list-style:none;}
#menuContainer{float:left;max-width:821px;width:100%;margin:0;padding-top:20px;margin-bottom:-20px;}
#siteMenu .mobileTitle{display:none;}
#siteMenu{height:60px;position:relative;list-style:none;font-size:14px;z-index:6000;box-shadow:none;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 10px;}
.dropDownMenu{position:relative;z-index:999;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.dropDownMenu > li > a{display:block;overflow:hidden;position:relative;text-indent:0;color:#000;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;background:0;border:0 none;height:auto;padding:15px 0;font-weight:400;}
.dropDownMenu ul{list-style-type:none;float:left;position:relative;z-index:9999;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul.menuColumn{border-left:none;border-right:none;}
ul.menuColumn:first-child{border:0;}
.widthcontainer2col ul.menuColumn{width:45%;padding:0 10px;}
.dropDownMenu ul.menuColumn a{text-decoration:none;display:block;letter-spacing:1px;color:#363636;font-size:13px;line-height:115%;margin:6px 0;}
.dropDownMenu li.menuLevel1{font-weight:700;letter-spacing:0;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;color:#4f2683;margin:5px 0;}
.dropDownMenu li.menuLevel2 > a{font-weight:400;}
.dropDownMenu ul a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.dropDownMenu ul.menuLevel1{float:none;}
.dropDownMenu .menuContainer{position:absolute;display:none;box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);border:1px solid #4f2683;background:#fff;z-index:9999;top:47px;padding:0;}
.dropDownMenu .innerContainer{float:left;width:100%;position:relative;z-index:99;}
.dropDownMenu .widthcontainer2col{width:50%;}
ul.dropDownMenu li:hover .menuContainer{display:block!important;}
ul.dropDownMenu li{float:left;cursor:pointer;}
ul.dropDownMenu li li{float:none;}
.widthcontainer2col{top:30px;z-index:999;}
.widthcontainer2col .innerContainer:before{position:absolute;content:"";z-index:-1;width:53%;top:12px;bottom:14px;right:0;border-left:1px solid #b9b9b9;}
.dropDownMenu>li:hover>a{position:relative;text-decoration:none;font-weight:700;background:#4f2683;color:#fff;}
#dropDownRootItem2{width:19.970631424376%;max-width:136px;}
#dropDownRootItem2:hover>a{background-position:center -21px;}
#dropDownRootItem3:hover>a{background-position:center -63px;}
#dropDownRootItem4{width:15.418502202643%;max-width:105px;}
#dropDownRootItem4:hover>a{background-position:center -105px;}
#dropDownRootItem5{width:16.446402349486%;max-width:90px;}
#dropDownRootItem5:hover>a{background-position:center -147px;}
#dropDownRootItem7 .widthcontainer2col{right:0;}
#dropDownRootItem1,#dropDownRootItem3{width:17.033773861968%;max-width:116px;}
#dropDownRootItem6,#dropDownRootItem7{width:16.096916299559%;max-width:124px;}
#dropDownRootItem7{width:16.096916299559%;max-width:124px;}
#dropDownRootItem6:hover>a,#dropDownRootItem7:hover>a{background-position:center -189px;}
#dropDownRootItem5,#dropDownRootItem6,#dropDownRootItem7{position:relative;}
#dropDownRootItem5 .widthcontainer2col,#dropDownRootItem6 .widthcontainer2col,#dropDownRootItem7 .widthcontainer2col{width:440px;}
.widthcontainer2col .innerContainer:before{position:relative;border-left:none;}
.innerContainer>.menuColumn:nth-child(1){width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;}
.dropDownMenu .widthcontainer2col{width:auto;}
#dropDownRootItem5 .widthcontainer2col,#dropDownRootItem6 .widthcontainer2col,#dropDownRootItem7 .widthcontainer2col{width:250px;}
.dropDownMenu .menuLevel2{padding:3px 0;}
.clearfix:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0;}
.clearfix{display:inline-block;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 840px){
#dropDownRootItem1{width:17%;}
#dropDownRootItem2{width:16%;}
#dropDownRootItem3{width:14%;}
#dropDownRootItem4{width:13%;}
#dropDownRootItem5{width:12%;}
#dropDownRootItem6{width:10%;}
#dropDownRootItem7{width:10%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
#dropDownRootItem1,#dropDownRootItem2,#dropDownRootItem3,#dropDownRootItem4,#dropDownRootItem5,#dropDownRootItem6,#dropDownRootItem7{font-size:12px;}
}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 619px){
#siteMenu{display:block;}
#siteMenu .mobileTitle{display:block;padding:15px;padding-left:30px;background-color:#4f2683;color:#fff;box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;}
#siteMenu>ul{list-style-type:none;width:89.5%;padding:0;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:10px;box-sizing:border-box;transition:all .5s ease;}
#siteMenu>ul ul{padding:0;list-style:none;}
#siteMenu a,#siteMenu li{margin:0;padding:15px 10px;color:#fff;}
#siteMenu .dropDownMenu>li{width:100%!important;box-sizing:border-box;padding:5px 0;cursor:pointer;}
.dropDownMenu>li>a{font-size:24px;background-color:#4f2683;display:block;margin:10px;pointer-events:none;}
.dropDownMenu>li>.menuContainer{font-size:16px;width:100%;height:100%;}
.dropDownMenu>li>.menuContainer>.innerContainer{opacity:.75;}
#siteMenu .menuColumn>li{padding:0;background-color:#fff;color:#4f2683;}
#siteMenu .menuColumn li a{color:#4f2683;}
#siteMenu li.menuLevel2{padding-left:0;}
#siteMenu .menuColumn>li>ul{padding:0;}
#siteMenu .menuColumn>li>ul>li{padding-left:0;margin:2px;}
#siteMenu .menuLevel2{padding:15px;}
}
@media print{
#siteMenu{display:none;}
h2{color:#000;font-size:25px;}
img{border:none;}
}
div,a,form,header{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;vertical-align:baseline;}
header{display:block;}
a,a:visited{color:#4f2683;text-decoration:none;}
a:active,a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
a{font-weight:700;}
#search-box a{font-weight:400;}
@media handheld, screen and (min-width: 620px){
.mobileOnly{display:none!important;}
#siteHeader{width:98%;margin:0 auto;max-width:1200px;}
#siteHeader{background:url() no-repeat scroll 2% 20px transparent;height:130px;position:relative;top:-10px;left:0px;}
#siteHeader > a{float:left;display:block;width:33.33%;height:26px;line-height:26px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;text-align:center;font-size:110%;}
a#logoLink{display:block;text-indent:-4000px;background-image:none;height:130px;width:222px;display:block;z-index:1;}
.search-tab,.search-tab-link{display:inline;color:#fff;background-color:#7bc143;text-decoration:none;padding:8px;cursor:pointer;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;}
.search-tab:hover{background-color:#807f83;}
.search-tab.selected{color:#fff;background-color:#4f2683;}
.search-tab-link{background-color:#009ddc;}
#search-box{position:relative;min-height:100px;clear:both;margin:-71px 0 0;float:right;display:block;z-index:999;padding:0;}
#search-box .search-bar{background:#fff;height:24px;border-bottom:1px solid #807f83;border-left:1px solid #807f83;border-top:1px solid #807f83;}
#search-box input{float:left;margin:0;}
#search-box input:focus{outline:none;}
#search-box #search-text-icon{float:left;width:auto;height:auto;position:absolute;right:0;margin:-1px 15px 0 0;cursor:pointer;}
#search-box #search-text{height:23px;width:75%;border:0;font-size:13px;line-height:23px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;background:transparent;color:#000;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 11px;}
.search-tab-content{background-color:#4f2683;padding:15px;margin-top:8px;}
#search-old-catalog{text-align:left;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1040px){
#search-box{top:40px;}
}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 619px){
#siteMenu{font-family:'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;}
#search-box{display:none;}
#siteHeader>a{background:#4f2683;}
#siteHeader>a{float:left;display:block;width:33.33%;height:26px;line-height:26px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;text-align:center;font-size:80%;}
#mobileLogo{background:transparent url() 0 bottom no-repeat;clear:both;height:133px;margin-bottom:50px;background-position:center;}
.mobileOnly{display:block;}
input[type="text"]{-webkit-appearance:none;border-radius:0;}
}
@media print{
.mobileOnly,#siteHeader{display:none;}
}
div,a,img{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;vertical-align:baseline;}
a,a:visited{color:#4f2683;text-decoration:none;}
a:active,a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
a{font-weight:700;}
@media print{
img{border:none;}
}
```

```html
<header id="siteHeader"><a id="logoLink" href="">Home</a> <a id="mobileLink" href="" class="mobileOnly">Hours</a> <a id="mobileLink" href="" class="mobileOnly">Catalog</a>
<div id="mobileLogo"><form id="search-box" action="">
<div  onclick="click1()" id="btn1" class="search-tab selected" data-search-type="catalog">Catalog</div>
<div onclick="click2()" id="btn2"class="search-tab" data-search-type="website">Website</div>
<div class="search-tab-link">Login</div>
<div class="search-tab-content">
<div class="search-bar">
<input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="Search Catalog" name="qu"><input type="image" alt="go" id="search-text-icon" title="Search" src="">
</div>
</div>
<div id="search-old-catalog"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Old Catalog</a></div>
</form></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code (including HTML and CSS) in the question, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Then open your console and read the errors

Comment: Post minimum examples. Not sure if the OP or someone else edited the question to add the giant css sample, but doing so makes the question less useful as now the relevant code is hidden away behind a wall of code.

Comment: Try passing an array instead `["search-tab","selected"]` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)

Comment: @ZohirSalak I tried that :( nothing.  https://jsfiddle.net/rvy9twmd/3/

Comment: like this`btn1.classList.add(["search-tab","selected"])` not `btn1.classList.add["search-tab","selected"]`

Comment: yea that is what I had, sorry if it wasn't updated

Comment: I don't get what I am doing wrong, console says buttons are being clicked? https://jsfiddle.net/rvy9twmd/4/

Comment: It'd be easier to see what's going on if you provided just the relevant CSS, rather than the whole file.

Comment: right sorry should I update?

Answer (score 3):

`classList.add` and `classList.remove` are variadic methods. To use them, pass in your classes as separate strings, rather than a single space delimited string.

`btn1.classList.add("search-tab selected");`

becomes

`btn1.classList.add('search-tab', 'selected');`

By the way, if you follow @j08691 's suggestion (read the console errors), it would have told you what was wrong. Reading your errors is good practice.

Comment: Ok I tried that but it still isn't changing the active tab. https://jsfiddle.net/rvy9twmd/2/

Comment: I don't get it, the console shows that my buttons are being clicked what is the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/rvy9twmd/4/

Comment: Your'e using incorrect syntax: `btn1.classList.add(['search-tab', 'selected'])`. Try the syntax I suggested in my answer, `btn1.classList.add('search-tab', 'selected')`.

Comment: You should look into guides debugging problems. https://codeburst.io/10-steps-to-solving-a-programming-problem-8a32d1e96d74

Comment: yeah I have been, but the debugger doesn't show me errors

Comment: Looking for errors in the debugger isn't the only way to solve problems; because, like you said, not every problem manifests in a debugger error. That's exactly why I suggest you take the time to learn how to debug problems.